# How do I add domain account users to SQL Server 2005 Windows Authentication List?

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-authentication

We recently moved from one domain to another and now I am trying to figure out how to tell SQL Server to authenticate the users in the new domain to log onto our SQL database. We use SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Enterprise manager, on the server name, you right click properties, and authentication (or security - it's been a while since I've managed SQL Server), and set authentication modes to "mixed".

Note that you can only add users to the database from Domains that are trusted/accessible by whatever domain the SQL server is a member of.

Once you've done that, you can add users by DOMAIN\Username in the Add Users collection.  Simply specify their domain username instead of a custom SQL name.